# Why can't java webapps have 2 webcontexts?

Tags: java, jetty

A java webapp must choose between either static context or "webcontext". Why do we need a webcontext just for a web server like jetty and why must we route everything to the same "webcontext" ?

Comment: From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) its one context per web app. If you say what the problem statement is then may be an alternate feasible solution can be identified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Jetty is a JEE servlet container and in the JEE world there is a one to one relationship between a webapplication and the web context. The intention is to be able to run several independent webapplications within the same servlet container. So it is easy to route to the appropriate webapplication by the first part of the URL path.

Theoretically it would be possible to declare more than one webcontext for a webapplication but it is specified otherwise. See section 10.2 "Relationship to ServletContext" in [Java Servlet Specification 3.1](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final-change-bar.pdf):

> The servlet container must enforce a one to one correspondence between
>   a Web  application and a ServletContext. A ServletContext object
>   provides a servlet  with its view of the application.

Comment: I'm not sure about Jetty but Tomcat allows you to share context between webapps (set crossContext = true, accessed via request.getServletContext()), which can allow you separate dynamic and static contexts. One use case for this was to have a set of dynamic webapps sharing a common set of static content. For reasons never explained to me the dynamic apps needed to serve their own content but it was all sourced from a CMS which would publish the "content" war file.  IMHO this is a hack that causes more issues than it solves but you can do it.